# Django CSRF verification failed even after adding csrf_token tag inside the form html

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-csrf

I'm working on a project using Python(2.7) and Django(1.10) in which I need submit the login form but it returns an error on submission.

> **Note:** I have searched a lot of questions tried various answers but in
>   most cases the `{% csrf_token %}` is missing from the `<form>` HTML
>   but in my case, I'm using this also, that's why don't mark this
>   question duplicated, please!

Here's what I have tried:

**from `form.html`:**

```
<form class="fields-signup" action="{% url 'mainlogin' %}" method="post">


{% csrf_token %}
            <h1 class="text-center">Sign In</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="user-name form-control" type="text"  name="username" placeholder="User name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="password form-control" type="password"   placeholder="Password" name="password">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn siteBtn" value="Sign In">
            <!-- <a href="#" class="btn siteBtn" >Sign Up</a>
            <p class="text-center">Don’t Have an account? <a href="#">Signup</a></p> -->


            <!--popup-forget-password-->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
             <button type='button' class="forget-password-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUpWindow">Forgot Password</button> 
              <!--forget-password-end-->
                <div class="col-sm-12 register">
                 <a class="register-driver-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUpWindow_register">Register Driver?</a> 
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

**from `urls.py`:**

```
url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
```

**from `views.py`:**

```
    if request.method == "GET":
    try:
        temp = get_template('login.html')
        result = temp.render(Context({'context': RequestContext(request)}))
        return HttpResponse(result)
```

**more from `views.py`:**

```
    if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    # email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    try:
        #obj = User_table.objects.get(user_name=username, emailid=email)
        obj = User_table.objects.get(user_name=username)
        if obj:
            print('got user obj')
        verify_password = ''
        try:
            verify_password = handler.verify(password, obj.password)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        if verify_password is True:
            request.session['user_id'] = obj.id
            request.session['user_type'] = obj.user_type
            user_name = obj.first_name + ' ' + obj.last_name
            request.session['user_name'] = user_name
            if not obj.approval_status:
                return HttpResponse('Your account is not confirmed by administration.')
            obj.is_active = True
            obj.login_try = 0
            obj.save()
            return redirect(home)
        else:
            try:
                # obj = User_table.objects.get(user_name=username, emailid=email)
                obj = User_table.objects.get(user_name=username)
                if obj:
                    s = obj.login_try
                    s = s + 1
                    obj.login_try = int(s)

                    if int(obj.login_try) >= 3:
                        obj.login_try = 3
                    obj.save()
                    if int(obj.login_try) == 3:
                        id = obj.id
                        key = get_random_string(length=10)
                        reset_link = 'It seems you forgot password or someone is trying to login you account. This is your password reset link please do not share this with other ' + settings.EMAIL_URL + 'reset_password/' + str(
                            id) + ' key is : ' + str(key)
                        send_mail('Reset link', reset_link, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [obj.emailid, ])
                        obj.password = str(key)
                        obj.save()
                        return HttpResponse(
                            'It seems you forgot password or someone is trying to login you account.  Password Reset link has been sent to your email id')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass
            return redirect(mainlogin)
    except Exception as e:
        print('error is  : ', e)
        return HttpResponse('An error has occurred.')
```

Also, I have included the `csrf` middleware in my `settings.py`.
what can be wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your browser inspector (eg chrome developer tools) and see if there's csrf_token in post request data. + see if additional `<input>` rendered in form. Also paste more from `views.py`, code that you posted is unclear.

Comment: where is the view where you are posting data

Comment: Hi @Exprator, I have added the code for `post` also. take a look, please!

Comment: The browser inspector shows that the post data as : `password abd37214
username abdul002`

Comment: In your `method == 'GET'` section change 3 lines to single one: `return render(request, 'login.html')` import is: `from django.shortcuts import render`. Will that work for you?

Comment: Now it returns `not a valid django_pbkdf2_sha256 hash` error on submission.

Comment: @AbdulRehman probably this deserves separate question. Guess this is about `handler.verify(password, obj.password)` line

Comment: is there any way I can generate a `django_pbkdf2_sha256 hash` password online?

Comment: @AbdulRehman See https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.django_std.html#django-1-4-hashes maybe this helps. If not, please create another question. We'll need additional stacktrace from your app

Comment: Actually, I have created the user manually and added the `hashed` password.now it's returning this error on submission :`malformed django_pbkdf2_sha256 hash (checksum must be exactly 44 chars`

Comment: And, it's returning from the `views` I have posted in the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if request.method == "GET":
    try:
        temp = get_template('login.html')
        result = temp.render(Context({'context': RequestContext(request)}))
        return HttpResponse(result)
```

[Docs about CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it)

> In the corresponding view functions, ensure that RequestContext is
>   used to render the response so that {% csrf_token %} will work
>   properly. If you’re using the render() function, generic views, or
>   contrib apps, you are covered already since these all use
>   RequestContext.

I'm not exactly sure why it's happening, maybe something wrong with context processors configuration, one of them adds csrf_token to context dictionary.
For more debugging see [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) section. But using builtin `render()` function will solve your problem as it'll handle context for you.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
if request.method == "GET":
    ...
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: The correct way to render the template with the request is `temp.render(request=request)`, but it's simpler to use the `render` shortcut like you have suggested.